# Edit iframe content using PHP, and preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, iframe, preg-replace, domdocument

I need to load some 3rd party widget onto my website. The only way they distribute it is by means of clumsy old `<iframe>`.

I don't have much choice so what I do is get an iframe html code, using a proxy page on my website like so:

`$iframe = file_get_contents('http://example.com/page_with_iframe_html.php');`

Then I have to remove some specific parts in iframe like this:

`$iframe = preg_replace('~<div class="someclass">[\s\S]*<\/div>~ix', '', $iframe);`

In this way I intend to remove the unwanted section. And in the end i simply output the iframe like so:

`echo ($iframe);`

The iframe gets output alright, however the unwanted section is still there. The regex itself was tested using regex101, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `DOMDocument` for parsing `HTML` content instead of regex.

Comment: Can you share your `HTML` content?

Comment: @SahilGulati not really, but here is equivalent `<div class="someclass">
        <span class="hot-line-text">
            hotline:
        </span>
        <a id="hot-line-tel" class="hot-line-link" href="tel:0000" target="_parent">
            <button class="hot-line-button"></button>
            <span class="hot-line-number">0000</span>
        </a>
</div>`

Comment: and what is your expected output?

Comment: @SahilGulati sorry, the code above is the one that i need to remove. The output code is much larger. All i need to do is to remove the code in my previous comment from the rest of the output

Comment: Hope my post will help you out..

Answer (score 1):

You should try this way, Hope this will help you out. Here i am using sample `HTML` remove the `div` with `given class name`, First i load the document, query and remove that node from the child.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/783944)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//sample HTML content
$string1='<html>'
        . '<body>'
            . '<div>This is div 1</div>'
            . '<div class="someclass"> <span class="hot-line-text"> hotline: </span> <a id="hot-line-tel" class="hot-line-link" href="tel:0000" target="_parent"> <button class="hot-line-button"></button> <span class="hot-line-number">0000</span> </a> </div>'
        . '</body>'
    . '</html>';

$object= new DOMDocument();
$object->loadHTML($string1);
$xpathObj= new DOMXPath($object);
$result=$xpathObj->query('//div[@class="someclass"]');
foreach($result as $node)
{
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo $object->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you for opening my eyes to DOM.so and all its convenience. This is a progressive approach indeed. My question was not solved however, the query returns nothing, i opened new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718492/domxpath-query-returns-nothing