# DOMxpath query returns nothing

Tags: php, iframe, domxpath

I need to load, modify and output some 3rd party `iframe` on my webpage. As suggested, I had created the intermediary page that simply contains `<iframe>` with its `src` attribute.

The php code that outputs the page looks like this:

```
$iframe->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://example.com/iframe_page.php")); //creating DOM object, see htm content below
$xpathObj= new DOMXPath($iframe);//creating DOMXPath object
foreach ($xpathObj->query('//div[@id="specific_id"]') as $node){ //this query returns nothing
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);//i need to remove the div with that id, but there is nothing to remove
}
echo $iframe->saveHTML($iframe->documentElement);//the iframe output works fine
```

And the content of my `iframe` looks something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="specific_id">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've even tried disabling JS to see if this div is placed there by front-end code and nope with JS disabled the structure of the document looks exactly the same.

Comment: Are you sure you have this `html` content? Because your code is working fine for above..

Comment: Your code is working check this https://eval.in/785036

Comment: @SahilGulati Im sure it is, its its structure anyway... What other things could be playing here?

Comment: Can you share your complete `HTML` content, because your above code is working fine here https://eval.in/785036

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather simple. You CAN'T manipulate iframe element crossdomain using PHP DOMDocument.